# pydocstyle printing debug information

Tags: python, docstring

I just installed pydocstyle in windows using pip:

```
python -m pip install pydocstyle
```

Now when I run it using a command like this:

```
pycodestyle "Z:/path/to/my/file.py"
```

It prints out a whole bunch of debug information like this:

```
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | got_newline: True
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.DEDENT ()
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | got_newline: False
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.NAME (_docs)
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | got_newline: True
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.OP (+=)
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | got_newline: False
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.STRING ('"""\n')
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,726 DEBUG   | got_newline: False
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,727 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.NEWLINE (
)
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,727 DEBUG   | got_newline: False
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,727 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.NL (
)
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,727 DEBUG   | got_newline: True
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,727 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.NAME (return)
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,729 DEBUG   | got_newline: False
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,729 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.NAME (_docs)
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,729 DEBUG   | got_newline: False
LA2PC018 2019-04-02 14:08:58,729 DEBUG   | parsing definition list, current token is tk.NEWLINE (
)
```

Is there a way to suppress this and just get the output? I seems like somehow it's being run in debug mode but I can't see how that's happening.

I'm using version 3.0.0.

```
$ pydocstyle --version
3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a configuration file that sets the `-d` / `--debug` option. `pydocstyle` will look for a configuration file in the directory of the file you checked, and every parent directory up to the root.

Look for a file in the [listed supported filenames](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/usage.html#configuration-files), and the first supported name found is used:

```
setup.cfg
tox.ini
.pydocstyle
.pydocstyle.ini
.pydocstylerc
.pydocstylerc.ini
.pep257
```

If that file has either a `pydocstyle` or a `pep257` section, it is used. By default, the search continues in parent directories too and the results are merged, see [*Inheritance*](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/usage.html#inheritance).

Somewhere in that process a `debug = True` configuration entry is found, and that setting causes this level of noise.

Either find those files and that line to disable it, *or* use the `--config` option to specify another file to be used for configuration. That file can just be empty.

If you are having issues with locating the configuration files, then you *could* run `pydocstyle --debug "Z:/path/to/my/file.py"` (so *start* with `--debug`) and the tool will print out, for every directory, if it is finding configuration files, and what files it has located if it does.

**That said**, there appears to be more going on in your specific case, `pydocstyle` explicitly configures the output handlers to only use the levelname and message parameters of log messages. Your output contains a date-time stamp and a `LA2PC018` prefix too, which indicates that **something else** is adding more logging configuration still. This suggest that perhaps a non-standard module is being imported that just happens to supply enough matching functionality to still work but also configures the logging framework with additional handlers.

If you run the tool with `python -v -m pydocstyle "Z:/path/to/my/file.py"` it'll produce a *lot* more outpu; this adds `import ...` logging output together with the files loaded for those imports. Comb through this to see if anything outside of the standard library, outside `site-packages` and not a `_frozen_importlib*` object is being imported.